# Best approach to set up a collection

Tags: nodes

I've got a bunch of internet links with the properties "Name", "Description", "URL", "Banner (image)" and "Category".

What is the best approach in Drupal to get these organised? Should I create a content type for it and then use e.g. Views etc. to format the output or is there a better way, maybe a module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a content type, e.g "Website"

Add fields:

1. URL ( [link](http://drupal.org/project/link) field )
2. Banner ( image field )
3. Category ( term reference field, create taxonomy vocab 'Category' first )

Name and Description will be the default node title and body fields

After that, you can create / manage your content.

Use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and/or [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) to control the output on your site.